# How to Make Aquamacs Color Theme Stick?

Tags: macos, emacs

So, I do a M-x color-theme-select and select a theme. Then I to Options -> Save options. I restart and its still the black on white theme.

I tried - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ

No use.

Tried downloading the theme (Charcoal Black) and put it in **/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs\ Emacs/customize.el**:

```
(load-theme 'charcoal-black t t)
(enable-theme 'charcoal-black)
```

Still not working. What to do now?

Comment: In my case there was an additional entry in the *custom-set-variables* section of *init.el* which then did override the settings. Could you check that?

Comment: @bdecaf I've a couple of settings like (background-color "Grey15") etc. I mean nothing in the lines of (load-theme '<theme>). Do you think this is overriding?

Comment: the relevant settings for me look like: `(custom-set-variables .... '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (deeper-blue))) ...`

Comment: color-theme-select and load-theme are from completely different packages, if the theme you want is available from color-theme-select then that is what you need to use in your init.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might certainly be better ways to solve it than this, but this works for me, there's no reason why it shouldn't work for you, and it has the merit of being instantly understandable:

- The function `color-theme-initialize` has to be run before a theme is chosen. This is done for you by `color-theme-select`, but you must do it manually or in an init file before specifying the theme.
- It seems many themes have a choice function: e.g `color-theme-charcoal-black` chooses `charcoal-black`. This and many others are available after the color themes have been init'ed, but not before.

Thus, I have in my `Preferences.el` these two lines:

```
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-charcoal-black)
```